# how we can write or read the session in cake php

Tags: session, cakephp

I am trying to write some data into the session and read from there, but I've got no success. Here is the code I tried:

```
$currentid =   $itemDetails['Item']['id'];
$currenttemid11 = $this->Session>write('itemy',$currentid); 
print_r($this->Session->read('itemy'));
```

but it doesn't show anything.

Comment: `$this->Session>write` is it typo or you have write your code this way (missing `->` before `write`)? Which CakePHP version are you using?

Comment: You should always mention the exact cakephp version you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a question on CakePHP 2.X or 3? I still haven't used CakePHP 3, but on the 2.X version `$this->Session` can be used only in controllers. I prefer

```
CakeSession :: write('variable_name', 'value');
CakeSession :: read('variable_name');
```

Comment: The reason it is only available in controllers is because you shouldn't be writing to the session from a model or a view because that is not the job of those classes.

Answer (score 0):

In CakePHP 3 you can do it like that:

```
$session = $this->request->session();
$session->read('name');
$session->write('name', 'value');
```

For CakePHP 2:

```
$this->Session->read('name');
$this->Session->write('name', 'value');
```

You can also find more information in the CookBook